# hibernate child class unknown column in in field list

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

So i'm writing a platform that consists of teams with researchers ( = 'onderzoeker' in Dutch ). Researchers inherit from Role because they need to be able to login with Spring security. Left out all the getters and setters but they are there! Thanks in advance :)

ERROR

```
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'onderzoeke0_.onderzoekerid' in 'field list'
```

Class Onderzoeker

```
 Class onderzoeker




@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue(value = "Onderzoeker")
public class Onderzoeker extends Rol {

@Column(name="onderzoekerid")
private int onderzoekerid;

@Column(name="onderzoekernaam")
protected String onderzoekernaam;

@Column(name="onderzoekervoornaam")
protected String onderzoekervoornaam;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="onderzoekerteamid")
protected Team team;


    @Override
    public String getType() {
        return "Onderzoeker";
    }

}
```

Class Role from which Onderzoeker inherits

```
package be.odisee.oxyplast.domain;


@DiscriminatorOptions(force=true)
@Entity
@Table(name="rollen")
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE )
@DiscriminatorColumn(name="type",
discriminatorType=DiscriminatorType.STRING)
@DiscriminatorValue("Rol")
public abstract class Rol implements Serializable {

@Id
@Column(name="id")
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
protected int id;



@Column
protected String status;

@Column(unique=true)
@Index(name="IRol_usernaam",columnNames="usernaam")
protected String usernaam;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="sessie_id")
protected Sessie sessie;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="persoon_id")
protected Persoon persoon;

public Rol(){}

public Rol(String status, String usernaam, Sessie sessie, Persoon persoon) {
    this.status = status;
    this.usernaam = usernaam;
    this.sessie = sessie;
    this.persoon = persoon;
}

public Rol(int id, String status, String usernaam, Sessie sessie, Persoon persoon) {
    this.id = id;
    this.status = status;
    this.usernaam = usernaam;
    this.sessie = sessie;
    this.persoon = persoon;
}
```

Well this needs to be enough the resolve the question. And yes the database is correct, it needs to be something else

Comment: Try adding the @Table(name="onderzoeker") annotation in your Onderzoeker Entity.

Comment: I can do that but i'll get a warning that that is illegal,  Illegal use of @Table in a subclass of a SINGLE_TABLE hierarchy: be.odisee.oxyplast.domain.Onderzoeker

Comment: have you the same name of your column "onderzoekeid" in db ?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, I finilly found both parent and child class need public 
 default constructor!

parent class:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class Order {

    public Order() {

    }
}
```

child class:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
@Table(name="ItemOrder")
public class ItemOrder extends Order {

public ItemOrder() throws Exception {
    super();        
}
```

I hope this answer helps someone.